# What is the internal point from which sum of distances to the vertices of n-sided irregular polygon is minimum?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

A friend who is been struggling with this question for past few days, asked me this question.

> What is the internal point from which sum of distances to the vertices of n-sided irregular polygon is minimum?

My guess is that the point should be centroid. But I can't prove it. I tried googling too but I only found about **Fermat's Point** which isn't  what I'm looking for.

PS: I've been trying the proof by assuming the polygon in argarand plane, I didn't go anywhere but just saying.

Comment: Let's see... this is really the geometric median problem, and at least as hard as that, so you will need to use numerical methods.

Comment: And no, the centroid is not the solution to the three-point problem.

Comment: Is there a reason for "complex-numbers" tag? Have you considered finding a solution using complex arithmetic or analysis?

Comment: @claws Can you sketch when there are four nodes? I was thinking like .. centroid of the minimal spanning tree.

Comment: This is known as Weiszfeld problem: https://web.iem.technion.ac.il/images/user-files/becka/papers/44.pdf

Comment: You can follow the formulation in Wikipedia for the [geometric mean problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) and feed the expression to a 2D function minimizer working over the coordinates of $y$.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, the polygon has no relevance here, you are just computing the distances to a finite point set.

Comment: The centroid minimizes the sum of the *squared* distances. In 1D, the minimum of the sum of [squared] distances is achieved by the median [mean].

Answer (score 0):

Let $$E:=\sum\|\mathbb x-\mathbb y_i\|=\sum\sqrt{(\mathbb x-\mathbb y_i)^2}$$ ($\mathbb x$ and $\mathbb y_i$ are vectors).

Then we minimize by

$$\nabla E=\sum\frac{\mathbb x-\mathbb y_i}{\sqrt{(\mathbb x-\mathbb y_i)^2}}=\mathbb 0$$

or

$$\mathbb x\sum\frac1{\|\mathbb x-\mathbb y_i\|}=\sum\frac{\mathbb y_i}{\|\mathbb x-\mathbb y_i\|}$$ which is a nasty nonlinear equation, to be solved numerically. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median#Computation)